# .php files working on localhost but not on webserver

Tags: php, get

I've created some kind of webshop for my highschool project. After building a filter system that searches through my database and loads them with the help of my self-written class product loader.

To set the filtervariables I've worked with `$_GET`. Everything is working perfectly fine on my localhost but when uploading to the server posed by my highschool only the header which I'm "requiring" separately works but anything else won't load.
Might it be that the server doesn't allow `$_GET` methods?

```
<?php

    $current_page = 'Webshop.php';
    require 'header.php';
    require 'includes\productloader.inc.php';
?>
<body>

<form method="get"action="Webshop.php">
<aside class="EDside">
    <div class="Filtersidebar">
        <h1>Filter</h1>
            <ul class="Filter">
            <li><a>Max. Höhe</a></li>
            <li><a>Max. Breite</a></li>
            <li><a>Max. Tiefe</a></li>
            <li><a>Metallart</a></li>
            <li><a>Max. Preis</a></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="Höhe"   value=""></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="Breite" value=""></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="Tiefe"  value=""></li>
            <li><select  id="Metallart" name="Metallart">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
                            <option value="Messing">Messing</option>
                            <option value="Kupfer">Kupfer</option>
                            <option value="Edelstahl">Edelstahl</option>
                            <option value="Aluminium">Aluminium</option>
                            <option value="Rostig">Rostig</option>
                        </select></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="Preis"  value=""></li>
            </ul>           



    </div>
    <div>
        <a href = Webshop.php><button>Zurücksetzen</button></a>
        <button type ="submit" >Anwenden</button>
    </div>
</aside>
</form>

<?php

    if(isset($_GET['Höhe'])){
        $maxhöhe;
        if(!$_GET['Höhe']=="") 
            $maxhöhe = $_GET['Höhe'];
        else 
            $maxhöhe = null;
        if(!$_GET['Breite']=="") 
            $maxbreite = $_GET['Breite'];
        else 
            $maxbreite = null;
        if(!$_GET['Tiefe']=="") 
            $maxtiefe = $_GET['Tiefe'];
        else 
            $maxtiefe = null;
            $metallart;
        if(!$_GET['Metallart']=="") 
            $metallart = $_GET['Metallart'];
        else 
            $metallart = null;
            $maxpreis;
        if(!$_GET['Preis']=="") 
            $maxpreis = $_GET['Preis'];
        else 
            $maxpreis = null;
        if($maxhöhe == null && $maxbreite == null && $maxtiefe == null && $metallart == null && $maxpreis == null) 
            $loader = productloader::withoutstatement();
        else 
            $loader = productloader::withstatement($maxhöhe,$maxbreite,$maxtiefe,$metallart,$maxpreis);
}
     else 
        $loader = productloader::withoutstatement();
        $productcount = count($loader->products);
?>

<?php

   if($productcount>0){
       echo '    
<section class="EDSection">
    <ul class="Skulptur">
        <li> <div class = "SBox">

                <div class="angebote">
                    <div class="angebot-bild">
                        <a href="showproduct.php?id='.$loader->products[0]->productid.'"><img class="a01" src="showimage.php?id='.$loader->products[0]->imgid.'" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="angebot-text">
                        <h1>'.$loader->products[0]->productname.'</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="angebot-preis">
                        <p>'.$loader->products[0]->preis.' EUR</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        ';
}

if($productcount>1){
    echo ' 
        <li><div class = "SBox">

                <div class="angebote">
                    <div class="angebot-bild">
                        <a href="showproduct.php?id='.$loader->products[1]->productid.'"><img class="a01" src="showimage.php?id='.$loader->products[1]->imgid.'" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="angebot-text">
                    <h1>'.$loader->products[1]->productname.'</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="angebot-preis">
                    <p>'.$loader->products[1]->preis.' EUR</p>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
        ';
}


if($productcount>2){
    echo '    
        <li><div class = "SBox">

                <div class="angebote">
                    <div class="angebot-bild">
                        <a href="showproduct.php?id='.$loader->products[2]->productid.'"><img class="a01" src="showimage.php?id='.$loader->products[2]->imgid.'" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="angebot-text">
                    <h1>'.$loader->products[2]->productname.'</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="angebot-preis">
                    <p>'.$loader->products[2]->preis.' EUR</p>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
        ';
}

if($productcount>3){
    echo '
        <li><div class = "SBox">

                <div class="angebote">
                    <div class="angebot-bild">
                    <a href="showproduct.php?id='.$loader->products[3]->productid.'"><img class="a01" src="showimage.php?id='.$loader->products[3]->imgid.'" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="angebot-text">
                    <h1>'.$loader->products[3]->productname.'</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="angebot-preis">
                    <p>'.$loader->products[3]->preis.' EUR</p>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
        ';
}
if($productcount>4){
    echo'
        <li> <div class = "SBox">

                <div class="angebote">
                    <div class="angebot-bild">
                    <a href="showproduct.php?id='.$loader->products[4]->productid.'"><img class="a01" src="showimage.php?id='.$loader->products[4]->imgid.'" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="angebot-text">
                    <h1>'.$loader->products[4]->productname.'</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="angebot-preis">
                    <p>'.$loader->products[4]->preis.' EUR</p>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
        ';
}
if($productcount>5){

  echo ' <li><div class = "SBox">

            <div class="angebote">
                    <div class="angebot-bild">
                    <a href="showproduct.php?id='.$loader->products[5]->productid.'"><img class="a01" src="showimage.php?id='.$loader->products[5]->imgid.'" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="angebot-text">
                    <h1>'.$loader->products[5]->productname.'</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="angebot-preis">
                    <p>'.$loader->products[5]->preis.' EUR</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>';
}
if($productcount>6){

    echo ' <li><div class = "SBox">

              <div class="angebote">
                      <div class="angebot-bild">
                      <a href="showproduct.php?id='.$loader->products[6]->productid.'"><img class="a01" src="showimage.php?id='.$loader->products[6]->imgid.'" /></a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="angebot-text">
                      <h1>'.$loader->products[6]->productname.'</h1>
                      </div>
                      <div class="angebot-preis">
                      <p>'.$loader->products[6]->preis.' EUR</p>

                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </li>';
  }    
  if($productcount>7){

    echo ' <li><div class = "SBox">

              <div class="angebote">
                      <div class="angebot-bild">
                      <a href="showproduct.php?id='.$loader->products[7]->productid.'"><img class="a01" src="showimage.php?id='.$loader->products[7]->imgid.'" /></a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="angebot-text">
                      <h1>'.$loader->products[7]->productname.'</h1>
                      </div>
                      <div class="angebot-preis">
                      <p>'.$loader->products[7]->preis.' EUR</p>

                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </li>';
  }         
?>
</section>



<section>
   <div style="text-align: center">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="Webshop.php">«</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="Webshop.php">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="Angebot2.php">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="Angebot3.php">3</a></li>

        <li><a href="Angebot2.php">»</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</section>


    <?php
    require 'footer.php';
    ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It could be your file path.  Did you upload the files to the includes subfolder?  Does the includes subfolder have read & execute permissions for "other"?  Also check the cAse of the files uploaded, most servers [not windows] are case sensitive. It shouldn't cause an issue, but you are using backslash in the path, / is more conventional.

Comment: What you can try is shift your php to the top since you hvae if to check isset your else will be to display the html portion. Another thing is `<form method="get"action="Webshop.php">` if you are submitting to the same php file, your action can just be `action=""`

Comment: @AlexBarker thanks for your help, indeed the \ instead of a / caused the issue.